# Finding a URL in a element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, youtube

I want to check if a textarea has a certain url with jquery
how can i go about doing this? Ive asked around and ive been told to use regEX, isn't there any way simpler?

And i mean part of a url 
Lets say user posts http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf5sbeEQQec
All im looking for is the www.youtube.com/watch?v= Part

Comment: Regexp is probably the best bet in  your case. It's not that hard to implement using JS either.

Comment: You say "a certain url". Do you always know exactly which url it is you're looking for?

Comment: @AndersDaniel yes, i will be looking for a youtube url :)

Comment: In that case Nix provided the answer you need.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have jQuery loaded in, as you've tagged it:

```
   var txt = $('textarea').text();
   var link = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/';

   if(txt.indexOf(link) > -1) {
     alert('Has link');
   }
```

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/6GHqa/

Comment: Im using .val instead of .text 
And it alerts has link when the link is copy pasted only, not when its typed out manually.
Im using keyup event btw, any solutions for that?

Comment: also this isn't the exact solution im looking for as it looks for the exact string from var link.
so i set var link = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
And the user puts in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf5sbeEQQec
Then its useless.

Comment: Incorrect Marshall. You would find that would work if a) you tried it or b) google'd "javascript indexOf"